# Trying to install wkhtmltopdf but get 404 Error

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to install wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 14.04, and the the first command is supposed to be this:

```
wget -nv http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

But I get the error "ERROR: 404 Not Found"

Why am I receiving this error? I don't see anyone else reporting this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkhtmltopd and read the readme, you will see that the repository recently changed. The correct links can now be found at:
http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/

And in your case you would now use:

```
wget -nv http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```